# How to create a command to load my own new .sty file

Tags: macros, packages, themes

I have created my custom class `myclass.cls` and I've put it into the BASE folder on MiKTeX dis. (`C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base`). Then I have created my `xxx.sty` file with some additional code, I've put it into the new folder OWNCLS (`C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\owncls`) and refreshed the file name database (FNDB) in MiKTeX settings. I hope I did everything how I should.

**And my question is:** How do I define `\newcommand` in `myclass.cls` that will load the `xxx.sty` file from its folder?

For example, when I want to create a new document, I will use command `\loadmytheme{xxx}` in the preamble. `beamer` class has got something similar `\usetheme{Themename}`.

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If by `base` directory you mean the directory with `article.cls` in, then that is not a good place, the `base` directory indicates the core LaTeX distribution and will get overwritten on any update.

Using `.sty` is not what you want here, if you *do* use `.sty` then you could load your additional package with

```
 \usepackage{xxx}
```

as normal.

If you name the files for your class themes in a unique way, say theme `xxx` gets stored in the file `xxx.mycls-def` then you can define a custom loading command in your class file something like

```
\def\usetheme#1{\input{#1.mycls-def}}
```

Or perhaps adding `\makeatletter` if your theme files need to allow `@`.

Comment: Ou thank you very much for this advices. So if i understand you right, i shouldn't create `xxx.sty` file with theme commands but i need to create some unique e.g. `xxx.thm` and after that i can use loading command in my class file. Just confirm me :) 
And one last thing.Should those `xxx.thm` files be in some special folder or can i keep'em in the folder where is `myclass.cls` located?

Comment: Any folder in your tex input path will do, the same folder as your class seems simplest (and would help packaging if you were ever to distribute this to others) But as I say, this should not be the base latex folder.

Comment: Thank you. I made it work but it gives me 1 warning.
"You have requested package '', but the package provides 'tropicana'."
Class (`\ProvidesClass{myreport}`) and theme (`\ProvidesPackage{tropicana}`) are in the same folder (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\myreport).
Can you help me how to get rid of this warning?

Comment: remove `\ProvidesPackage{tropicana}` because that is not a package but one of your theme files.

Comment: David Carlisle, BIG thanks to you! Everything works :) have a good day.